# SVD in matlab for image compression

Tags: image, matlab, compression, svd

[image: The image of a characteris given for your referecnce]I have used SVD in matlab using the inbuilf function 'svd'. My original image size is 60*60 and I am able to reconstruct the image with an N= 38. 
The code I have used is as follows ( Which was posted by masad) :-

```
[U,S,V]=svd(inImageD);

dispEr = [];
numSVals = [];
for N=5:2:60
     % store the singular values in a temporary var
    C = S;

    % discard the diagonal values not required for compression
    C(N+1:end,:)=0;
    C(:,N+1:end)=0;

    % Construct an Image using the selected singular values
    D=U*C*V';

    figure;
    buffer = sprintf('Image output using %d singular values', N)
    imshow(uint8(D));
    title(buffer);
    error=sum(sum((inImageD-D).^2));

    % store vals for display
    dispEr = [dispEr; error];
    numSVals = [numSVals; N];
end
```

But the reconstructed image I get with an N= 38 is also of 60*60 with rows from 50 onwards has '0' values ( I mean row 1to 50 is nonzero values). I would like to know why I am not getting the  reconstructed images as a smaller matrix ( instead of 60 *60).

Comment: Could you include your test image as well, please.

Comment: I have added the image. thank u